# 4 images on the right as sidebar

Tags: html, css, image, multiple-columns, sidebar

I want to create a fluid design with header (full-with), big image slideshow on the left and 4 images as sidebar.

I want to make the sidebar 100% height, with 4 images (which will act as buttons). The height should always be 100%, so no scroll. Width should automatically change when resizing browser.

But I couldn't get it done. Do you have any suggestion?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmJba/1/)

Thank you very much!

```
    <html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
width: 100%;

}
div#links {
    float: left;


}

div#rechts {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: grey;

}

div#rechts img {
    height: 25%;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
}

div#cat {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}


header {
    height:10%;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header id="header">header</header>

<div id="links">
    Content left side
</div>
<div id="rechts">
<div id="cat"><img src="http://blog.erikmeijs.we-ict.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/meeuw-1024x682.jpg" /></div>
<div id="cat"><img src="http://blog.erikmeijs.we-ict.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/meeuw-1024x682.jpg" /></div>
<div id="cat"><img src="http://blog.erikmeijs.we-ict.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/meeuw-1024x682.jpg" /></div>
<div id="cat"><img src="http://blog.erikmeijs.we-ict.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/meeuw-1024x682.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle

Comment: This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmJba/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap 2 or 3 for making fluid and responsive websites simple and easy to use once get hang of it you can pretty much do anything with bootstrap you can easily div them in to separate grids to do the way you would like.

Comment: Thank you. Bootstrap seems great, i really want to get into that. But for now, shouldnt there be an easy fix to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Tricks is a great place to start more user friend forum also can search post your message in there but also show code sample what your trying to achieve

Comment: I have searched there, but couldn't find it. I've got it working now in all browsers, except FF. The images keep floating somewhere in the middle and do not stick to the right side. Something to do with clear or something? Any idea?